# Coldfusion Yahoo contacts import

Tags: coldfusion, yahoo-api

Can anyone help me to import yahoo contacts to a website, I followed the steps in http://developer.yahoo.com I got the access token using the `signature_method=plaintext` but when I use the access token and try to retrieve contacts using `HMAC-sha`1 signature method I am getting an error

> OAuth oauth_problem="signature_invalid", realm="yahooapis.com"

Can someone help me on this.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)